# Congratulation page not showing the variable from the number-guessing game

Tags: php, html

I have a php script for a number-guessing game and an html script for a congratulation page.  If the guess is correct, the game will end and the congratulation page will open.  In the php, I have a variable $prize=1000-100 * $_POST['tries'], such that if the first guess is right, the player will win $1000; if the player has a second guess, the prize will be $100 less, and so on.  This variable is saved in a hidden field in the php as $_POST['prize'].  I hope the final prize can be printed in the congratulation page, but it didn’t work as I expected.  Did I do anything wrong in the html?  Thanks guys, Maria.

guess.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['number'])) {
   $num = $_POST['number'];
} else {
   $num = rand(1,10);
}
if(isset($_POST['prize'])) {
   $prize =1000-100 * $_POST['tries'];
} else {
   $prize = 900;
}
$tries=(isset($_POST['guess'])) ? $_POST['tries']+1: 0;
if (!isset($_POST['guess'])) {
    $message="Welcome to the Guessing Game!";
} elseif (!is_numeric($_POST['guess'])) {
    $message="You need to type in a number.";
} elseif ($_POST['guess']==$num) {
    header("Location: Congrats.html");
    exit;
} elseif ($_POST['guess']>$num) {
    $message="Try a smaller number";
} else {
    $message="Try a bigger number";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $message; ?></h1>
<p><strong>Guess number: </strong><?php echo $tries; ?></p>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<p><label for="guess">Type your guess here:</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="guess" name="guess" />
<input type="hidden" name="tries" value="<?php echo $tries; ?>"/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $num; ?>"/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="prize" value="<?php echo $prize; ?>"/>
</p>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

congrats.html:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<title>Congratulation!</title>
<body>Congratulation!<br/>
You Won <?php echo $_POST['prize']; ?> dollars!
</body>
</header>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the value to the congrats page, using either GET request or a session. I'd recommend using a session so people cannot alter the prize value.

Just amend this part here:

```
} elseif ($_POST['guess']==$num) {
    $_SESSION['prize'] = $_POST['prize'];
    header("Location: Congrats.php");
    exit;
}
```

Then (you need to change the congrats page to a php page to use the session btw to enable php)

Congrats.php

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<title>Congratulation!</title>
<body>Congratulation!<br/>
You Won <?php echo $_SESSION['prize']; ?> dollars!
</body>
</header>
</html>
```

PS: Session will also require session_start() at the top of both documents.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your script will work, but you'll need to change `congrats.html` to `congrats.php` because html is static and php is dynamic. Also you might want to use sessions because anyone can inspect-element and change the value.